# Setting width for DIV inside table cell

Tags: html, css

In My ASP.NET Application, I have a table.
Eventhough I set column width, it changes in the browser (100px column becomes 96px or 108px).
I have `div` inside the `th` tag. If I set 100px width to the `div`, It comes out of the `th` as the rendered column width is 96px. What's the solution for making the column width exact ?
Please Don't tell me to make 100% width for `div`, as its using absolute position (For making the table header fixed.)

```html
<table border="0" cellpadding="1">
 <tr>
  <th align="center" width="100px">
   <div style="width:100px;">PV#</div>
  </th>
  <th align="center" width="90px">
   <div  style="width:90px;">Date</div>
  </th>
  <th align="center" width="100px">
   <div  style="width:100px;">Payment Doc#</div>
  </th>
  <th align="center" width="410px">
   <div  style="width:410px;">SOA Payments</div>
  </th>
    
  <th align="center" width="100px">
   <div  style="width:100px;">Payment Made</div>
  </th>
 </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: the th and div are not changing in width as you mentioned. width change may be due to any other style sheet affecting it

Answer (score 0):

Your TH tags have padding on your example. To have the exact width of the div inside each TH you need to set padding to 0.

```html
<table border="0">
  <tr>
    <th style="padding:0;">
      <div style="text-align:center;width:100px;">PV#</div>
    </th>
    <th style="padding:0;">
      <div style="text-align:center;width:90px;">Date</div>
    </th>
    <th style="padding:0;">
      <div style="text-align:center;width:100px;">Payment Doc#</div>
    </th>
    <th style="padding:0;">
      <div style="text-align:center;width:410px;">SOA Payments</div>
    </th>

    <th style="padding:0;">
      <div style="text-align:center;width:100px;">Payment Made</div>
    </th>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But unfortunately, It didn't fix my issue. My 'th' doesn't have a padding; 
setting the css style table-layout:fixed; solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Since all `th` and `div` have fixed width, it is not changing width as you mentioned.

`cellpadding="1"` this will add `2px` to the `th` width.